# How to host a blockchain decentralised application?

Tags: blockchain

Till now, I have worked on centralised application in which there is one web server and one database server. Now when I started exploring about block-chain, I came to know that it is a decentralised application. Now, question arises in front of me is, how to host a block-chain decentralised application?

It might be a silly question but here i want to understand this concept more deeply.

Please help to clear my above query.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Most current Ethereum Dapps are not quite decentralised. There is generally one or more contracts, that are deployed to the blockchain (so do not need hosting), and a web component, consisting of static HTML, CSS and JavaScript, that interacts with the blockchain via MetaMask or similar.

In most cases, this web component is hosted on an inexpensive static hosting provider, such as GitHub pages or a CDN, although users can also download it and host it locally (indeed MyEtherWallet recommend users do this).

In the future, it's expected that more dapps will use a decentralised solution to host this content, such as IPFS or Swarm, but these are both relatively cutting edge technologies, and have not yet seen widespread adoption.

Comment: Hi Jems,Thanks for your answering.Let me tell you one thing.Please undertand your answer in simple language.

Comment: I thought I'd used fairly standard terminology. Which parts are difficult to understand?

Comment: I tells you.What I understand till now.We create a smart contract.And  migrate it on Ethereum  local block-chain natwork(**Ganache**).When I successfully migrate.Then it create contract json file. Connect our  blockchain network to **metamask**.Create a client side frontend(Html,css,js).I create a **dist** folder.In which I move my *src* folder(Html,css,javascript) and contract json.Then I publish this folder into ipfs.And run my decentralize application.So, blockchain application deploy this type of scenario.So this steps is right or wrong??

Comment: Question is also arise in my mind where is my decentralise application hosted.When I access my decentralise application.I have to always use meta coin wallet for transaction.It can be internally.How it can be happen??

Comment: The smart contact code is stored on the blockchain, which is to say that every machine running an Ethereum node such at Geth or Parity stores it. When you broadcast a transaction, these nodes use the code they stored earlier to check that the transaction is valid, and check what side effects it would have. If the fee is high enough, one of them may accept the transaction into the blockchain, and that transaction is now permanent.

Comment: Your workflow is mostly right, but note that Ganache is a fake blockchain used for testing. Once you're happy with the results of your testing, you follow the same procedure, but with a client that talks to the production mainnet blockchain, such as Geth or Parity.

Comment: One thing I can not understand your answer is that If the fee is high enough one of them may accept transaction into blockchain .So it depends of fee,If fee is higher then the transaction into blockchain.

Comment: Yes, I glossed over this, since it's part of how the blockchain works, and is probably explained better in other questions. In short, transactions are added to the blockchain in blocks, adding blocks to the blockchain takes a lot of computing power, so the people who do it (called miners) receive a reward for doing so - a fixed reward per block, plus transaction fees for any transactions in that block (so they usually choose the transactions that pay the highest fees)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which blockchain you want to deploy your contract (on which blockchain will your Dapp have it's info and resources stored).

If you want to have it on a public blockchain such as Ethereum, NEO... By just joining them protocol, you can deploy your contracts into them and by the way, get access to all of the data stored on it. And your Dapp will have also a way to interact with that blockchains users.

It'll be decentralized because each party that joins the blockchain, each miner, and each node, without trusting each other, arrive at a consensus about the state of the blockchain.

> State: a set of information that represents the “current state” of a system; determining whether or not a transaction is valid, as well as the effect of a transaction, should in the simplest model depend only on state. Examples of state data include the UTXO set in bitcoin, balances + nonces + code + storage in ethereum, and domain name registry entries in Namecoin.

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum's blockchain is called the 'World Computer' in that anyone who *participates* in the protocol has access to it's resources.

By hosting a decentralized app you would pay a *fee* and that would enable you to run it on the Ethereum network.

[This](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook) is a great introductory explanation of what blockchain is and how it works with regards to Ethereum. Hope it helps :)

Comment: The document linked has been deleted. Where can I find it?

Comment: @DavidTaubmann Sorry the delay. https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook